# add summary output in Rstudio

Tags: r, plot, summary

Is there a generic way to add some `summary($some_variable)` inside a plot. I use `mtext(summary($some_variable))` but `mtext` do not convert the object to a string. So how to do that ?

More specifically, I use some `ur.df` Dickey Fuller test, but this output some complex object. However, when I run `summary($some_variable)` in the console, I get a correct output that I want to display inside the plot, or if this is not possible, to display it inside some Shinyapp

Comment: You can use `capture.output` to get the printed summary results as a string, e.g., `summ = capture.output(summary(rnorm(100)))`

Comment: @Gregor thank you it si exactly that, could you add it as an answer plz ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question correctly. But...

Why not save the statistics as a string variable first. Than, use the string variable as a sub-title?

For example:

```
library(datasets)
library(highcharter)

data(mtcars)

text <- as.character(quantile(mtcars$mpg))

highchart() %>% 
  hc_chart(type = "column") %>% 
  hc_title(text = text) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(categories = 2012:2016) %>% 
  hc_add_series(data = c(3900,  4200,  5700,  8500, 11900),
                name = "Downloads")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save as a string anything that prints to the console with `capture.output`, for example:

```
string = capture.output(summary(rnorm(100)))
```